# Possible to Trigger CodeDeloy to deploy code on codeCommit Push Trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, version-control

I have setup a deployment of code in code-commit. I have my code present in CodeCommit. As soon as there is a code pushed to master branch, i want that master branch code to be pushed to production (which is through codeDeploy).

Is there any way i can setup a trigger to start the deployment? 
Perhaps through codepipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/)** is exactly what you need. If you want to configure it through the AWS web console it will guide you through the process, if you want to set it up e.g. in *CloudFormation* I can help you with that as there are some nitty-gritty details to work through.

You can also look at **[AWS CodeStar](https://aws.amazon.com/codestar/)** that is supposed to wrap the whole CI/CD experience on AWS in a single interface. Since you already use *CodeCommit* and *CodeDeploy* it may make sense to add *CodePipeline* and *CodeBuild* and do it all through *CodeStar*.

Hope that helps :)